# Vertical align div and fit image inside it

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to create a very simple image viewer. When you click a thumbnail, a large version of that thumbnail should open on a black background with 0.8 opacity. That image...

- may not exceed 80% of the window height.
- may not exceed 80% of the window width.
- should be centerd horizontally and vertically.
- should always keeps it aspect ratio.
- may not be a background image.
- should not be changed with javascript.

My biggest problem is that the height of the image inside the div exceed that 80% window height (80wh) when you check it on mobile devices (see Chrome's device toolbar). The strangest thing is that my div is working fine: it's maximum height is 80vh... Here's my code, perhaps somebody sees the mistake I'm making:

```css
#gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Gallery {
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.Gallery-imageWrapper {
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}

.Gallery-close {
    background: rgb(21, 21, 21);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
}

.Gallery-image {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gallery">
    <div class="Gallery-imageWrapper">
    <a class="Gallery-close" href="#" title="Sluiten">x</a>
        <img class="Gallery-image" src="https://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Screenshot website Optiek Cardoen" title="Website Optiek Cardoen">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried other CSS properties like object fit, width, height, position, ... on the image element, but nothing seems to fix it. Anyone who can help me please? :)

Thx!

Comment: You say the height is 80vh but the CSS says 80%, that's not the same.

Comment: Percentage max-width is calculated based on container's width not max-width, same for max-height from height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use viewport units, try with `vmin` - equal to the smaller of `vw` and `vh`.

Key style:

```css
.Gallery-image {
  max-width: 80vmin;
  max-height: 80vmin;
}
```

Full demo:

```css
.Gallery {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.Gallery-imageWrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.Gallery-close {
  background: rgb(21, 21, 21);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Gallery-image {
  max-width: 80vmin;
  max-height: 80vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gallery">
  <div class="Gallery-imageWrapper">
    <a class="Gallery-close" href="#" title="Sluiten">x</a>
    <img class="Gallery-image" src="https://placehold.it/600x600" alt="Screenshot website Optiek Cardoen" title="Website Optiek Cardoen">
  </div>
</div>
```

In addition:

CSS selectors are generally case-insensitive; this includes class and ID selectors. Make sure you keep it consistent.

Comment: You are my hero of the day, Stickers! It works <underline this please>great!</underline this please>. Thanks a lot, I'm very happy now. Learned some new, great CSS stuff :D

Oh, and forgot to mention: I'm using Suit CSS as a CSS naming convention: https://github.com/suitcss/suit/blob/master/doc/naming-conventions.md ;)